how many electrodes for earthing a building
I have a building with 25~30 apartments 6 kW ~ 10 kW electricity registrations and a set of three motors for pumping water to a tank at the top, each nearly 800 W. Anybody can detail the specifications of the earthing part. How many electrodes, diameter and depth?

You have a building with 30 apartments and no contact at the utility provider who will tell you the local regulations?

Typically, the requirements for diameter and depth of an earthing electrode as specified by the electrical code that applies in your country. It is important that all earthing electrodes be bonded together independently of the ground wires in your electrical circuits.

you mean the electricity company?
